# How do I get value from ocrTextBox (2552)?

Tags: php, jquery, preg-match, getvalue

I Have This
How to get value from ocrTextBox(2552)
????????????

```
$res='<script>
$("#submit_i2ocr").removeAttr("disabled");
$("#tools").show();
var aTag = $("a[name='resultsTag']");
$("html,body").animate({scrollTop: aTag.offset().top-50},"slow");
$("#ocrTextBox").val("2552\n").show();$("#ocrTextBox").css("direction","ltr");
</script>';
```

Help

Answer (score 0):

I am not fully understand, maybe you can try this way:

```js
$("#ocrTextBox").val()
```

Comment: I used php.How to do it

Comment: You can use jquery